# UITableViewCell's view's frames changing after being set

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I have a dynamic cell that gets added in after receiving a response from our server. Depending on that response, it will configure the cell a little differently. When configuring it with one specific response, the frame of the Title label seems to reset after being added.

I've set breakpoints throughout my code, and have narrowed it down to changing sometime after `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` is called. It is fine all the way up until this method. I'm not sure what else is called after `heightForRowAtIndexPath:`, so I'm not sure where else to set breakpoints to investigate.

I can post some code if necessary, not sure which code to post right now to help out.

More Info:

- The frames are not touched by any of the data source methods
- The frame's height is the issue, it goes from 17 to 8 at some point after `heightForRowAtIndexPath:` is called.
- This only happens on iPhone 4s, iPhone 5, and iPhone 5s running iOS 7.1, which leads me to believe that it is a 32 bit processor problem, along with some code in 7.1 that assumes a 32 bit processor maybe? Not sure on the 5s.

Any guidance on where to look would be greatly appreciated. I can post up some code if you guys need any, just not sure which code would be helpful right now to help you guys debug, since I'm not even entirely sure what methods are being called after `heightForRowAtIndexPath:` that are messing my frame up.

Thanks in advance!

Quick edit: The row is added using a begin/endUpdates block. It is the only row added. I've posted that code below:

```
if ([self.tableView numberOfRowsInSection:AccountHomeTableSectionBody] == [self numberOfCellsWithPossibleDynamicPlacementCells] - 1) {
        [self.tableView beginUpdates];
        [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:rowPosition inSection:AccountHomeTableSectionBody]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
        [self.tableView endUpdates];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you overridden -(void)layoutSubviews? That seems to be where tableview cells are arranged.